# Datagridview to tabcontrol dragdrop Winforms

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, drag-and-drop, tabcontrol

What I am needing to get accomplished is to make it where the user can drag and drop rows from datagridview and hover over a different tabpage and I will add the rows to the datagridview on that tabpage.

```
Private Sub datagridview_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview.MouseDown
    mouseDownPosition = e.Location
End Sub

Private Sub datagridview_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview.MouseMove
    If CheckMouseMovement(sender, datagridview, e) Then
        listofBuilds = New List(Of Build)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.Rows
            If Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells.Item(0).Value) Then
                Dim t As Build = DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, Build)
                listofBuilds.Add(t)
            End If
        Next
        If listofBuilds.Count > 0 Then
            dataGridView.DoDragDrop(sender, dropEffect)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl_DragEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TabControl.DragEnter
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TabControl.DragDrop
    Dim DropPage As TabPage = GetTabPageByTab(TabControl.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y)))
    If DropPage IsNot TabControl.SelectedTab Then
        If DropPage Is Page1 Then
        If DropPage Is Page2 Then
        If DropPage Is Page3 Then
           //etc
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetTabPageByTab(ByVal point As Point) As TabPage
    For i As Integer = 0 To TabControl.TabPages.Count - 1
        If TabControl.GetTabRect(i).Contains(point) Then
            Return TabControl.TabPages.Item(i)
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

It never gets to the drag enter part of my code, which I figued out it was cause I forgot to allow drag and drop for each of my pages by setting AllowDrop = true. I fixed my issue by getting a tabpage based on the X and Y coordinates inside my tabcontrol. Hope this is useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code worked for me to move data from one page to another

```
Private Sub TabControl_DragEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TabControl.DragEnter
   e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TabControl.DragDrop
    Dim DropPage As TabPage = GetTabPageByTab(TabControl.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y)))
    If DropPage IsNot TabControl.SelectedTab Then
       If DropPage Is Page1 Then
       If DropPage Is Page2 Then
       If DropPage Is Page3 Then
          //etc
       End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetTabPageByTab(ByVal point As Point) As TabPage
   For i As Integer = 0 To TabControl.TabPages.Count - 1
       If TabControl.GetTabRect(i).Contains(point) Then
           Return TabControl.TabPages.Item(i)
       End If
   Next
   Return Nothing
End Function
```